# Unexpected CSS result using IE8 with styling links

Tags: css

I've styled links using CSS like the example below.

This is working as expected in Chrome however with IE8 I'm having this problem:

When you first visit the page all links do not have underline as expected.

If I hover on them they get underlined as expected.

If then visit the link the underline disappears as expected however if I again hover on them I don't get the underline anymore.

Any ideas...?

Thanks

```
a:link {color:#0064cc;font-family:Arial;font-size:13px;text-decoration:none !important;}     
a:active {color:#0064cc;font-family:Arial;font-size:13px;text-decoration:none !important;}     
a:hover {color:#0064cc;font-family:Arial;font-size:13px;text-decoration:underline !important;}  
a:visited {color:#0064cc;font-family:Arial;font-size:13px;text-decoration:none !important;}
```

Comment: try put a:hover row at the end of the list of properties (after a:visited)

Comment: Don't use `!important`

Comment: This is not !important related, see the answer from @theftprevention below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem comes from the fact that your links aren't styled in [**LVHA order**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3alink). You should style them with `:link` first, then `:visited`, then `:hover`, then `:active` for consistent cross-browser results.

Additionally, any style applied to `:link` doesn't need to be reapplied to `:visited`, `:hover`, or `:active` unless you want to override it with a different value. For example, when you declare `text-decoration:none` for `:link`, you don't need to put that in any other definitions except for `:hover`, where you want to override it to `none`. Since all of the styles except for `:hover` are the same, you can kind of bypass the LVHA order here:

```
a:link, a:visited, a:active {
    color: #0064cc;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 13px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Hope this helps!

### Edit

Although your issue isn't related to your use of `!important`, it is generally a good idea to avoid using it. It leads to some pretty non-semantic CSS. It's better to have a comprehensive understanding of the order in which CSS selectors are applied (it's not as simple as you might think!). Check out the MDN's [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Selectors) for more info.

Comment: You're right, thanks a lot, wasn't ware of the fact that the order matters!

Comment: And yes I'm aware of the recommendations above we are planning to style them differently so just preparing the ground :)

Answer (score 1):

Try to list the different selectors in the correct order.

`a:hover` MUST come after `a:link` and `a:visited`
`a:active` MUST come after `a:hover`

Also, you should not use `!important`. This can cause you problems later.

Src: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_link.asp

Answer (score 1):

Just have a read about CSS selectors specificity, and reorder your styles rules:

http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#specificity

And try to avoid `!important` like the Devil avoids the Cross.